# I want when I type the search word it searches all sites and browsers and shows the results

Tags: python

I have an application that I want when I type the search phrase it searches in Google and brings me the results, which are links to sites
code

```
print("Search In Websites: ")
search = input()
if (search) :
    print(search + " , PLEASE WAIT ...")
    if (search) :
        show = print(search)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in `urllib` and `re` (regulare expression) modules of Python.

```
import re
import urllib.request as ur

browser = "https://www.duckduckgo.com/search?q="
searching = browser + "+".join(input("searching: ").split(' '))

source = ur.urlopen(searching)
source = str(source.read())

output = re.findall(r'''(?:http://|www.)[^"]+''', source)
for i in range(len(output)):
    print(output[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the googlesearch library can help you with this.

Firstly on the terminal, execute the command `pip install googlesearch-python`

Then write the following code in your python file:

```py
from googlesearch import search
print(search("query"))# Inside search() write the query you want to search in google
```

You would find all URL's of websites as output that have information about the query you wanted to search.